# Brew upgrade error: ...php/8.14 is not a directory

Tags: php, homebrew

I couldn't find any hints to this on Google, but I recently try to perform a 'brew upgrade' and I have received the following error:

```
 ⚓  ~  brew upgrade
==> Upgrading 6 outdated packages:
Error: /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.1.4 is not a directory
```

Any idea how to resolve this error?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66137934/macos-change-default-php-version-with-homebrew/66138426#66138426

Comment: @AnantKumarSingh I saw that before, it doesn't help.

Comment: If you  cd to ‘/usr/local/Cellar/php/‘ and then ‘ls’ what do you see?

Comment: I’ve noticed sometimes the directory gets renamed to 8.1.4_reinstall and if you rename it you can fix the brew error

Comment: I had the same problem with a different version of php: Error: /usr/local/Cellar/php/8.1.3 is not a directory. Adding this note so it will match internet searches who have the version I'm running. The rename option above by Andrea worked for me.